# how to write this grails searchable query

Tags: grails, searchable, grails-searchable

In a grails project, some of the domain classes have a "region" field (not all of them). The logged in user is belonged to one the regions. I want to search those objects that
1- Does not have a region field OR
2- Their region field is equal to current user's region

How to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by an alternative method. I used a property with special unique value on region and added it to search query.